# useState does not set state when initalized by RouteProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks

I have a component that uses useState. The state is initialized with a property from RouteComponentProps. It works when I type the url in the browsers addressbar, but not when URL is changed by a Link-tag. What's the difference? How can I set the state when url is changed by the Link-tag?

Using the code below and navigating to /test1 shows test1/test1 from the line

```
{text}/{props.match.params.text}
```

Pressing the link "go" changes the URL to /erik but shows test1/erik. Why?

```
interface RouteProps {
    text: string | undefined
}

const Test: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps<RouteProps>> = (props) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState(props.match.params.text || '');

    return (
    <div>
        <h3>{text}/{props.match.params.text}</h3>
        <Link to="/erik">Go</Link>
    </div>
    );
}

const routes = <div>
    <Route path='/:text?' component={ Test } />
</div>;

render(<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} children={ routes } />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is the code in Stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-c7pvsp

Comment: i was reading something today like this. check this https://kevgathuku.me/2018/06/07/a-practical-use-case-for-reacts-componentdidupdate/

Comment: componentDidUpdate when changing the state, sorry for not providing answer im new to react myself.

Comment: Do you really need a state here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value you pass to `useState` will only be set once as its initial value, afterwards the parameters you give to it will be ignored. If you wish to update the text on a prop change, I recommend using `useEffect` instead. It would look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setText(props.match.params.text || '')
}, [ props.match.params.text ]);
```

The function you pass as first argument to `useEffect` will execute depending on whether the values in the array you pass as second argument change. So if the text from the prop changes, it will execute the function and set the state with the new value.